# Picture class number-order of the simple groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, gap, simple-groups

Every simple group below are assumed non-abelian.

Let us call the *class number* $k(G)$ of a finite group $G$ the number of its conjugacy classes (also, the number of its irreducible complex representations, up to equivalence). Here is the computation of the order and the class number of the first finite simple groups:

```
gap> it:=SimpleGroupsIterator(10,10000);
<iterator>
gap> for G in it do Print([G,Order(G),NrConjugacyClasses(G)]); od;
[ A5, 60, 5 ][ PSL(2,7), 168, 6 ][ A6, 360, 7 ][ PSL(2,8), 504, 9 ][ PSL(2,11), 660, 8 ][ PSL(2,13), 1092, 9 ][ PSL(2,17), 2448, 11 ][ A7, 2520, 9 ][ PSL(2,19), 3420, 12 ][ PSL(2,16), 4080, 17 ][ PSL(3,3), 5616, 12 ][ PSU(3,3), 6048, 14 ][ PSL(2,23), 6072, 14 ][ PSL(2,25), 7800, 15 ][ M11, 7920, 10 ][ PSL(2,27), 9828, 16 ]
```

In the following picture, the points are $(k(G),|G|)$ with $G$ simple of order less than $10^8$.

[image]

My laptop can hardly compute such a picture for finite simple groups of order up to $10^9$ or $10^{10}$.

**Question**: Could you post your best such picture (computed yourself or found in the literature or on the web or elsewhere) which would be significatively better than above one?

*Observation*: Using `NrConjugacyClassesPSL` we can show that $k(\mathrm{PSL}(2,2^n)) = 2^n+1$, for $n \le 50$.

*Bonus question*: Is it true for all $n$?

*Remark*: The curve which appears in the middle of the picture should have equation $\frac{1}{2}(2r-6)(2r-5)(2r-4)$ and its points should exactly be given by the groups $\mathrm{PSL}(2,q)$ with $q$ odd prime power (see the bonus of [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/349037/34538) for more details).

Comment: The number of representations equals the number of conjugacy classes (which will be faster to compute), using `NrConjugacyClasses`.

Comment: If you run through all groups, your image will be overwhelmed by PSL2(q) or, more generally, a few classes such as PSL and PSU. There must be a formula for the number of classes for these groups, depending on Lie-Rank and field size, while the group order also is a polynomial, depending on Lie Rank, in the field size. I suspect that explains the curve yoiu see.

Comment: @ahulpke: yes, I found exactly $\frac{1}{2}(2r-6)(2r-5)(2r-4)$ for the main curve in the middle by considering $\mathrm{PSL}(2,3^n)$. It should work for every $\mathrm{PSL}(2,q)$ with $q$ odd prime power, surprising!